# Is it possible to set a modifier as a QShortcut?

Tags: qt, pyside, maya, pyside2, qshortcut

```
shortcut = QtWidgets.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence(QtCore.Qt.Key_Shift), MayaMainWindow)
shortcut.setContext(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationShortcut)
```

I have a system in place for overloading Maya shortcuts, as and when needed. I want to do this with the shift key, however simply writing it as above seems to do nothing. Not even an error message.

I have tried

```
QtGui.QKeySequence(QtCore.Qt.Key_Shift)
QtGui.QKeySequence(QtCore.Qt.Key_Shift + QtCore.Qt.SHIFT)
QtGui.QKeySequence(QtCore.Qt.Key_Shift + QtCore.Qt.NoModifier)
QtGui.QKeySequence(QtCore.Qt.Key_Shift + QtCore.Qt.NoButton)
```

I want to run a custom shortcut when *only* the shift key is pressed.

Comment: From the [source code: qshortcutmap.cpp](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/kernel/qshortcutmap.cpp.html#_ZN12QShortcutMap9nextStateEP9QKeyEvent): "// Modifiers can NOT be shortcuts...".

Comment: Sad times. If you put that as the answer, I'll set this as resolved. Thanks!

Comment: I've managed to hack something together with an event filter, which works for me as I don't need to overload this particular maya command (as it does nothing in the mode I am using).
    --def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        --if self.use_shift_shortcut.isChecked():
            --if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Type.KeyPress:
                --if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Shift:
                    --# do stuff

Comment: Using an event-filter is not a hack. Trying to make QShortcut do things it wasn't designed for would be a hack.